# Html table not populating from ViewModel

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I am trying to populate an HTML table with data from a table in my database. The issue is simply that the HTML table is not getting populated with any data.

Here is the ViewModel:

```
    public class TestViewModel
{
    public string MatchedId { get; set; }
    public string UnmatchedId { get; set; }
    public string Auth { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreditDate { get; set; }
    public string CreditNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal CreditAmount { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeniedDate { get; set; }
    public int DeniedReasonId { get; set; }
    public string DeniedNotes { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Action:

```
   [HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadValidationTable(HttpPostedFileBase csvFile)
{
    var inputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
    {
        SeparatorChar = ',',
        FirstLineHasColumnNames = true
    };
    var cc = new CsvContext();
    var filePath = uploadFile(csvFile.InputStream);
    var model = cc.Read<Credit>(filePath, inputFileDescription);

    try
    {
        var entity = new Entities();

//model here is the .csv, doesn't have anything to do with this issue
        foreach (var item in model)
        {
            var tc = new TemporaryCsvUpload
            {
                Id = item.Id,
                CreditAmount = item.CreditAmount,
                CreditDate = item.CreditDate,
                CreditNumber = item.CreditNumber,
                DeniedDate = item.DeniedDate,
                DeniedReasonId = item.DeniedReasonId,
                DeniedNotes = item.DeniedNotes
            };
            entity.TemporaryCsvUploads.Add(tc);
        }
        entity.SaveChanges();

        System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);

//This is where the database table is getting filled
 entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Insert into CsvReport Select  p.Id as MatchedId, case when p.Id is null then t.Id end as UnmatchedId, p.Auth,p.CreditDate, p.CreditNumber,p.CreditAmount, p.DeniedDate,p.DeniedReasonId, p.DeniedNotes from TemporaryCsvUpload t left join PermanentTable p on p.Id = t.Id;");


        TempData["Success"] = "Updated Successfully";

    }
    catch (LINQtoCSVException)
    {
        TempData["Error"] = "Upload Error: Ensure you have the correct header fields and that the file is of .csv format.";
    }

    return View("Upload");
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<TestProject.TestViewModel>

                        @if (Model != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in Model.Where(x => x.IdMatched != null))
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @item.MatchedId
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.Auth
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.CreditDate
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.CreditNumber
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.CreditAmount
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.DeniedDate
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.DeniedReasonId
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.DeniedNotes
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    }
```

It's a little weird because I am populating the database with an SQL command. What am I missing here? Do I need to try and pass it through the controller action? Let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

**Edit**

I tried to pass the instance through, but I may still be doing it incorrectly:

```
         var testModel = new TestViewModel();

         return View("Upload", testModel);
```

Here is what its padding through:

```
    public class TestViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Test> Test { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: You are returning just a view without the actual model you want to use in the page?  You need to pass the IEnumerable<TestProject.TestViewModel> instance to the view you return for it to populate the page.

return View("Upload", viewModelList);

Comment: How do I pass the instance to the view in `return View()`

Comment: Overloading. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View%28System.String,System.Object%29

Answer (score 0):

Made an answer so essentially the view doesn't know what to render you need to pass an actual filled model (in your case an IEnumerable to the view).  This can be done using the method:

```
View("Upload", viewModelList);
```

[Controller.View docs on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View%28System.String,System.Object%29)

Comment: I tried this, but it is still not populating. How is the instance of the viewmodel passing the data if I am using a query to fill the db. I made an edit above to show.

Comment: You have to fill it like any other object, there is no way that I am aware of to link your db collection directly to the view unless there is a collection you can bind your view to, but I wouldn't recommend that.  Essentially you must select your data from the database into your view model to pass as the Model to the view.

For each entity.TemporaryCsvUploads.Add(tc); add a value to a List<TestProject.TestViewModel>.  That is the list you want to pass to your view.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not adding any data to your view model.
If your view model is a collection of Test objects, you need to add some
Test objects to the collection.

```
var model = new TestViewModel()
{
    Test = new List<Test>() { new Test(), new Test(), ... }
}
return View("Upload", model);
```

Comment: Also, you code is pretty inconsistent, please clean it up a bit and it would be easier to help you out.